# ODBC Connector for Highrise - Power BI connector not working, what is the issue?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, odbc, powerbi, highrise

I am trying to connect PowerBI with Highrise CRM using CData's (the company's), ODBC Connector but every time I try to test the connection, it gives a '401 unauthorized' error. I have admin rights in both, the system and Highrise, the credentials are correct as well. It does not open a browser window asking for access, as it should once it's successfully connected.

I created the app as required and put in the Redirect URI as http://localhost:2435, both in the app as well as the connector. I tried resetting the connection, tried removing the connector and adding it again but nothing seems to work. I get the same error every time. I have also triple checked the OAuth 2.0 credentials from the app and they are correct as well.

I am not able to figure out where exactly the problem lies. I have the log file for it but I am not sure what part of it would be beneficial to post here to troubleshoot.

Comment: Based on the documentation for the ODBC Driver (http://cdn.cdata.com/help/BHE/odbc/pg_connectiono.htm): Highrise uses the OAuth authentication standard. To authenticate to Highrise, you will need to obtain the **OAuthClientId**, **OAuthClientSecret**, and **CallbackURL** by registering an app with Highrise. You will also need to set the **AccountId** to connect to data. Do you have all of those values set?

Comment: Hi Jerod Yes, all of these values are set exactly as per the documentation.

Comment: Interesting. Well, you likely don't want to post your logfile here, since it likely contains sensitive data. If you haven't already, reaching out to the CData [Support Team](https://www.cdata.com/support/submit.aspx) is likely your best bet. When they resolve your issue, be sure to post it here as the answer to your question.

Comment: So I was using the API key as the OAuth access token as I confused them both. All I needed to do was remove the OAuth access field.